# cheque printing application in java

Tags: java, printing

I want to develop an application in Java which takes data (ex.name of person, Amount) from excel-sheet and print it on cheque. I can able to access data from excel-sheet but don't know how to print that data on cheque. Data must get print on appropriate location on cheque (ex. name should get print where blank space is given for name). please give me a guideline for this. Thank you in advance. I am not native English speaker so kindly ignore my mistakes.

Comment: It might also be that you need an OCR-B or such **OCR font** to be automatically readable by the bank. Page sizes and positions are no problem. Look for sample code. Format specifications must exist, because not only you had that problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would [create a PNG image](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/) for each record, with a transparent background and [data at the right place](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#drawString(java.lang.String,%20int,%20int)). Then I would launch the [printing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/print/PrinterJob.html) of these images .

That sounds hacky and someone might have a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a reporting tool. You can see examples here: http://www.dynamicreports.org/